# Maxwell Boltzmann distribution of speed

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, gas, boltzmann-equation

I am currently reading 'Concepts in Thermal Physics' and in its chapter 5 it is written that fraction of molecules traveling with speed between $v$ and $v+\mathrm{d}v$ corresponds to a spherical shell in velocity space of radius $v$ and thickness $\mathrm{d}v$. I am just not able to understand this part. Please help.

Comment: Please add the specific page of the book. If possible, quote the text by typing it out ([do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/168783)). For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) instead.

Comment: You should elaborate on what you don't understand to make the post self-contained and more specific.

Comment: in velocity space v takes the same role as r in conventional space, so the analogy is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine, you have a box at finite temperature so that all the particles are moving randomly at random points in random directions. Now, you can associate to each particle, a velocity vector. Move these vectors parallely such that they start from the same origin. Since, your vectors were totally random (direction and modulus), they will make a solid sphere. The points $(x,y,z)$ in this sphere will determine the vector. Now, speed is $v^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2$ in this space, which is same for $(x',y',z')$ following the above constraint. This constraint also forms a spherical shell. Hence, the shell dv would contain the vectors whose speed is from $v$ to $v+dv$. Its a standard recipe and will be used many times in your further studies.